# About WordPress child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created wordpress child theme from parent theme "twentythirteen". My child theme name is "twentythirteen-child".It has following content.

```
/*
 Theme Name:   twentythirteen-child
 Theme URI:    http://www.example.com
 Description:  A Twenty Thirteen child theme 
 Author:       WPBeginner
 Author URI:   http://www.example.com
 Template:     twentythirteen
 Version:      1.0.0
*/

@import url("../twentythirteen/style.css");
```

Unfortunately my child theme replaces the parent theme and newly created theme is applying when i activate child theme and there is no parent theme style is applied on webpage.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to try:

- Double check to make sure your template path in the header you posted actually goes to the twenty-thirteen theme. That could be why the base styles aren't appearing.
- Your child theme needs it's own `style.css` - you can't import that. Read more on the [WordPress Child Theme Codex Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).
- Make sure you didn't copy over the *entire* directory into the child folder. That's a common beginner mistake.
- Your child theme is *supposed* to override the parent theme. It supersedes any parent theme files you put into it. For example, if you put a different `page.html` in the root of your child theme, it would replace the `page.html` from the twenty-thirteen parent theme.

Comment: Thank you @staypuftman.
I was creating header.php fle in my child theme directory in that i wrote my own header.
That's why it was not applying.
Thank You.

Comment: @BhautikAndhariya - glad I could help. Could you please mark this question as answered properly? Thank you.